# Access 2010 ADO on Windows XP Mode (in ADDE format)

Tags: ms-access, ado

I have a problem with ADO in My application. I have Access installed on my computer with Win7Pro and there I can use both version (ACCDB and ACCDE). But only ACCDB works under runtime (with SP1) in WinXPMode environment.

There is the code

```
Dim strSQL As String, Cnxn As ADODB.Connection, Rsxn As ADODB.Recordset
Dim lngDummy As Long
lngCount = DCount("[Sklad]", "cisSklad", "[Zobrazit]")
CountData = lngCount
If CountData = 0 Then Exit Sub
ReDim ItemValues(lngCount - 1)
Set Cnxn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
Set Rsxn = New ADODB.Recordset
...
```

In ACCDE (under RunTime on XPMode):
The line Set Cnxn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection return the message Error 13: Type mismatch.

I have the reference to ADO 2.8.

*Debug.Print CurrentProject.AccessConnection: Provider=Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=C:\Work\SkladII\Sklad.accde;User=Admin;Data Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0*

All tables in sklad.accde are linked

Do you have any idea, where is the problem?

Comment: The same error for both objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigate whether this issue is confined to early binding for ADO in WinXPMode.  Remove the reference for ADO and revise your code to use late binding.

```vb
Dim strSQL As String, Cnxn As Object, Rsxn As Object
Set Cnxn = CurrentProject.Connection
'Set Rsxn = New ADODB.Recordset
Set Rsxn = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Comment: I can't explain.  I just speculated something was not right with the ADO 2.8 reference in WinXPMode.  Late binding will allow Access VBA to  utilize an available version --- though I have no idea how the choice of version is made when late binding.  I think an ACCDB can adjust when the specific referenced version is not available/usable ... but ACCDE can't because your code can't be re-compiled in that case.  Anyway I always use late binding for ADO in production applications to avoid any such early binding troubles; it just makes my life easier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for making my life easier too :)